# bada 2.0 SDK; anyone use it?

Tags: mobile, sdk, bada

http://developer.bada.com/events/bada2.0-Now-Live

Samsung has release 2.0 SDK for bada.
Anyone tried to installed it? What are the differences 2.0 has from 1.2??

Comment: You can find some information here: http://developer.bada.com/article/Whats-new-in-bada-2-0 I won't install it till i can upgrade it on my phone

Answer (score 3):

I've been playing it for a while. Unfortunately, currently, you can't deploy anything on physical hardware with the currently available (unofficial) Wave I/II firmware, not even as of the latest version (XPKH2). Nevertheless, the emulator works just great.

We've been discussing this issue at http://ask.badadev.com/questions/4161/official-20-sdk-and-xpkh2-on-wave-ii and http://www.samfirmware.com/apps/blog/show/8212522-samsung-released-bada-2-0-0-sdk-#comments (also follow the developer.bada.com link there; can't post it directly becauase of the two-link limit for newly registered accounts).

Comment: Will bada 2.0 be available for the Wave I?

Comment: @user714965 Wave I is the same hardware as Wave II. If it works for II it'll work for I.

Comment: "Will bada 2.0 be available for the Wave I?" - it will be, at least according to Samsung. However, they only promise the official 2.0 firmware for Q4. The folks at http://www.sammobile.com/threads/425-When-will-Samsung-release-bada-2.0. state the Wave I version it'll be released this month.

Comment: "Wave I is the same hardware as Wave II. If it works for II it'll work for I." - not entirely the same hardware, device driver-wise: the LCD controller is different. (This is why, for example, there still isn't a working port of Android for the Wave II, unlike the Wave I.) That is, the upgrades / firmwares, while highly similar, aren't compatible.